# Does query response time vary dependant on number of matched records

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

If I have a table of 100,000,000 records, and I do a selection query for a single value, would I expect the query performance to differ greatly depending on whether there are 10 or 10,000 matched records?

As an example -

```
SELECT * FROM OrderLines ol
WHERE ol.Account = '12151'
```

would return 10 rows

```
SELECT * FROM OrderLines ol
WHERE ol.Account = '9551'
```

would return 10,000 rows.

Am I expecting both queries to take equally as long? How would this outcome change with or without an index?

Comment: If more than one record matches, how can you query for a single value? Can you add an example?

Comment: I can't imagine there being any difference in execution plans. There might be a difference in response time when populating or displaying the result, however that will not be a result of the execution plan.

Comment: you could test it and look at the [query stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx)? Performance will depend greatly on the complexity of your query, your schema and any indexes on the table in question. Seeing as none of that information is provided, this question is a bit broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, it will take longer. Whether it takes greatly longer depends on your definition of greatly. Seeing as the query is a simple query on a single table it will be fast regardless as long as you have an index starting with `OrderLines.Account`. However, you should avoid using `SELECT *` unless you really need all columns. It reduces the options the query parser has available to it and it may need to make extra reads to get some of the data.

Longer answer using a generic query not returning `SELECT *`

Let's say you have a query

`SELECT Value1 FROM dbo.Table1 WHERE Value2 = 123;`

and an index on `Value2`, the likely query plan would be to perform an index seek on that index. What happens then depends on whether the index is a covering index (includes `Value1`).

If it is then it will read each of the 10 or 10,000 records during the index seek and have all the information it needs available to it.

If it's not then it will read each record and then also need to perform another read to get `Value1`.

In either case it will take longer for 10,000, but more so if the index is not covering. Note that the clustered index is always a covering index when querying a single table as the leaf nodes contain all columns.

Comment: If you measured it then you would find that, in the absence of an index there is very little difference in performance. The larger result set will be slightly slower due to the buffering and transfer of the data, but the slow part, reading and checking each row, is the same for both queries. But with an index there will be a big difference since the DBMS needs to the sloe thing much note often.